# when I minimize the app, the app is not showing in task manager

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I have developed android app its working fine but when I minimize the app, the app is not showing in task manager

after opening the app press on home button app need to be displayed in taskmanger running apps to resume app

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Could you post your code? Have you implement onStop, onPause functions?

Comment: And also post your manifest file

Comment: post your manifest here and logcat also

Comment: what code I need to post to understand my problem

Comment: post this file of your project    https://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Raw/AndroidManifest.html

Comment: @MohanGanesh, check my answer, carefully read about the Manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is, may be in your Manifest file, in the launcher activity you have defined this tag, if you want to see your app in the recent list, just remove this tag.

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check carefully if you accidently added below line in your manifest and remove it if it is there:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true" //<----
```